# Getting the length of an array inside an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a JavaScript object which includes an array. I created a new key, `length`, which is supposed to store the value of the length of the `fields` array.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var data = {
    "label": "Information",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "name",
            "label": "Team Name",
            "type": "string",
            "config": {}
        }
    ],
    "length": fields.length     // Need help with this line
};
$("button").click(function() {
    alert(data.length);
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kvtywmtm/

In my fiddle, nothing gets alerted, although it should alert 1, since there is 1 record in the fields array.

Any ideas?

Edit

I know you can get the length OUTSIDE of the object by creating a new variable

```
var length = data.fields.length;
```

However, I need the length to be inside of the object.

Comment: You have no `fields` variable so you'll get a ReferenceError. You can't just use an identifier and hope the language will understand what you want.

Comment: Then how can I reference the length of that field in my object?

Comment: Why not `alert(data.fields.length)`?

Comment: @RichardHamilton: Depends. Do you want only the initial value? Or do you want it always to represent the current `length` of the array? You say you want to "store" it, so it doesn't sound like you always want the current length.

Comment: I actually have an array containing many of these objects. I need to know the length of the `fields` array that's in each of these so I can add custom code. This is just a small example of the code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [**getter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = {
    "label": "Information",
    "fields": [{
      "name": "name",
      "label": "Team Name",
      "type": "string",
      "config": {}
    }],
    get length() {
      return this.fields.length
    }
  };
  $("button").click(function() {
    console.log(data.length);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click Here</button>
```

Comment: @RichardHamilton: FYI, works on IE9+. There's no way to patch it in IE8 and lower. Since you're using jQuery, I assume you need some legacy support,.

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = {
    "label": "Information",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "name",
            "label": "Team Name",
            "type": "string",
            "config": {}
        }
    ],
};
data.length = fields.length;
```

This won't auto-update the `length` field, but it doesn't seem as if you need it to.

Comment: I was looking to have the length key inside of the object

Comment: @RichardHamilton I'm sure AmmarCSE's solution will work wonderfully for you then. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/7x2wsqde/)

I don't know what length you need in the alert, but if you need the object  `data` properties length you need the following. Also, to pass `fields`length you need to add it after declare the array:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = {
        "label": "Information",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "name",
                "label": "Team Name",
                "type": "string",
                "config": {}
            }
        ]
    };

    data.length = data.fields.length

    $("button").click(function() {
        alert(Object.keys(data).length);
    });
});
```